# Write values returned from function as a list

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a function:

```
    difference(values[["x","y"]],n,m)
```

which calculates the difference between x and y for year n and n+1 between years 2010 and 2020.
For example,

```
    difference(values[["x","y"]],2010,2011)
```

returns an arbitrary number 5.

I wish to write this so that it calculates the difference between x and y for every n and n +1, for example all of the following

```
    difference(values[["x","y"]],2010,2011)
    difference(values[["x","y"]],2011,2012)
    difference(values[["x","y"]],2012,2013)
    ...
    difference(values[["x","y"]],2019,2020)
```

written as a list. I have tried this:

```
    for i in range(2010, 2021):
        print(difference(values[["x","y"]],i,i+1))
```

but it clearly doesn't work.

Comment: The only issue I can see is that it should be `range(2010, 2020)` since you want your final `i` to be 2019

Comment: Your question is not clear to me - do you want to print all the values, or put it into a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
for i in range(2010, 2021):
        print(difference(values[["x","y"]],i,i+1))
```

In this loop i takes as value only 2010. `range` with 2 arguments take the min and max. You should use `range(2010, 2020)`